# Debian Squeeze + dist-upgrade + how to rollback

Tags: networking, usb, upgrade, debian-squeeze

Recently, I have dist-upgrade on Debian Squeeze which runs my Proliant DL360 G5. After this, when the OS boots up I can see that there is a problem with udev - it's failing. Also, there is no network now and I cannot find a node for USB device in /dev.

The machine does not have CD drive, but has USB ports of course.

The question is: is it at all possible to somehow bring the USB and network back to operable state?

Comment: What were you ugprading from?

Answer (score 0):

(not exactly an answer)

The version of [wajig](http://code.google.com/p/wajig/) in Debian Wheezy allows you to backup each package before it gets upgraded:

```
$ wajig help upgrade

Upgrade all of the installed packages.
$ wajig upgrade
options:
  -b            backup packages about to be upgraded onto some default directory
  --backup=DIR  backup packages about to be upgraded onto a given directory
  -n --noauth   skip the authentication verification prompt before the upgrade
```

So just run `wajig --backup=<backup directory> upgrade` so that in case of trouble, you can jsut run `dpkg --install <DEB file>` inside the direcories (which BTW are timestamped).